# How can i measure steps while walking or jogging with Android?

Tags: android

Is it the SensorManager API that i have to use to measure steps? Any sample code or tutorial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen this?

http://code.google.com/p/pedometer/

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. Wonder how we can do that in iPhone?Any link?

Comment: Checked this link but there isn't any code there:
http://code.google.com/p/iphone-pedometer/downloads/list
Can you look into it?

Comment: Go to the Source tab and click Browse to browse through the source code.